# Django native query v "homemade" sql query to json

Tags: python, django

The following code works nicely:

```
def jsonLiveLeaderboard(request):

    data = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(fixturematchday=12)

    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', data)

    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

However, if I try to do the same with a homemade query like so:

```
def jsonLiveLeaderboard(request):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        """
            select username as User, floor((count(Goals)/2)-(if(sum(Loss)>0,1,0))) as Round, sum(Win) as Wins, sum(Goals) as Goals, sum(Loss) as Losses from
            (select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.hometeamscore<f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.hometeamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid and s.user_id = u.id union all
            select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.awayteamscore>f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.awayteamscore<f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.awayteamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.awayteamid and s.user_id = u.id) t
            group by username, campaign
            having Losses = 0
            order by Round DESC, Wins DESC, Goals DESC
        """)

    pointsCurrentSeasonLive = cursor.fetchmany(size=8)

    json_data = serializers.serialize('json', pointsCurrentSeasonLive)


    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /jsonLiveLeaderboard/
'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Is there an easy way to convert a "homemade" query to json in much the same way you can with a native Django query?

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializers.serialize` is specifically for Django querysets. You just have a list, so you should use the standard json library:

```
json_data = json.dumps(pointsCurrentSeasonLive)
```

Comment: Great swift response, thank you.  Got a different error but your answer solved the question :)